# HTML5 not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I've just launched a site, but when I view it in IE11, all my styling is gone! All my tags like `<header>` just render `<header></header>...content...</header><//header>`. Same with section and footer tags.

I added html5shiv, which fixed some parts, but now my footer isn't showing 100% width.

Does anyone know why this may be doing this? The site is at www.linkup.co.nz. I'm not sure what other info I need to post, but I can add more if requested. :)

Comment: Check that you have a `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I do but doctype is lowercase. Does that matter?

Comment: No it does not, how you did it was fine.

Comment: Seems strange. Provide more information.

Comment: @knitevision what information do you want?

Comment: post your full html DOM code here

Comment: @dpDesignz The site includes `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`. IE8 did not recognize HTML5 elements.

Comment: You could change that to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is not validating. Try fixing the three errors (namely the unclosed tags) and I bet it works as expected:

[Validate www.linkup.co.nz](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=%20www.linkup.co.nz&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Line 132, Column 552: End tag section seen, but there were open elements.

```
`...paint-smart.png" width="271" height="70" alt="Paint Smart" /></a></section>`
```

Error Line 131, Column 28: Unclosed element div.

```
`<div class="container">`
```

Comment: Wow such rookie mistakes! I can't believe I didn't think to Validate it. Thanks Justin. That works.